# Paired-T test error in R not all arguments have the same length

Tags: r, t-test

The following error is put out when I want to perform a paired t-test:

```
t.test(materix_first_timepoint[,1], materix_second_timepoint[0,1], paired=TRUE)
```

> Error in complete.cases(x, y) : not all arguments have the same length

This is the str of my matrices:

```
str(materix_first_timepoint)
 num [1:35, 1:4] 23.28 12 3.81 28.63 10.25 ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : NULL
  ..$ : chr [1:4] "1 hour" "2 hours" "3 hours" "4 hours"

 str(materix_second_timepoint)
 num [1:35, 1:4] 13.9 25.5 17.8 18.9 22.7 ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : NULL
  ..$ : chr [1:4] "1 hour" "2 hours" "3 hours" "4 hours"
```

If I perform a t-test with `paired=FALSE` it works. I do not understand what going wrong.

Comment: Could you check `length(materix_first_timepoint[,1])`, and `length(materix_second_timepoint[0,1])`? See what you get

Comment: I think you should think back to the statistics behind what you're doing i.e what do you think `paired` is used for? It is important to know what the argument is supposed to do and use it according to known theory. The lengths need to be the same because according to [the theory](http://www.statstutor.ac.uk/resources/uploaded/paired-t-test.pdf), you need to "pair" the observations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, you are trying to compare one column of the first `matrix` (`materix_first_timepoint[,1]`) with 0 values in the  `materix_second_timepoint[0,1]`, so it can't work.

Instead try `t.test(materix_first_timepoint[,1], materix_second_timepoint[,1], paired = T)`.